# Samba Share: Guest login doesn't work after Wheezy --> Jessie

Tags: debian, samba

When I was still using Wheezy, I was able to access my Samba shares on my LAN with no problem. But after updating to Jessie, both Windows and my Android phone give me: SmbAuthException: Logon Failure

I'm still using the same smb.conf as before:

```
[global]
workgroup = HOME
netbios name =myDrive
server string = BananaPi
security = user
disable spoolss = yes
log file = /var/log/samba/samba.log
syslog = 0
max log size = 100
dns proxy = no
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE
use sendfile = yes
aio read size = 16384
aio write size = 16384
deadtime = 30
guest account = root

[myDrive]
path = /media
read only = no
available = yes
browseable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
public = yes
```

The log is pretty empty:

```
[2015/10/12 15:47:00.759016,  0] ../source3/lib/util_sock.c:446(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): setsockopt: SO_REUSEPORT = true on port 137 failed with error = Protocol not available
[2015/10/12 15:47:00.761053,  0] ../source3/lib/util_sock.c:446(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): setsockopt: SO_REUSEPORT = true on port 137 failed with error = Protocol not available
[2015/10/12 15:47:00.761454,  0] ../source3/lib/util_sock.c:446(open_socket_in)
  open_socket_in(): setsockopt: SO_REUSEPORT = true on port 137 failed with error = Protocol not available
[2015/10/12 15:47:00.763518,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:136(daemon_ready)
[2015/10/12 15:47:02.325451,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:136(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connectionsopen_socket_in(): setsockopt: SO_REUSEPORT = true on port 445 failed with error = Protocol not available
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections*****

  Samba name server MYDRIVE is now a local master browser for workgroup HOME on subnet 192.168.1.70

  *****
```

I know if I'd need a password if I wanted to access this from the web, but for now I just want to get LAN access working again, and then I'll focus on WAN.

I've tried using my password for 'root' to log in, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `security = user` to `security = share` or specify valid users in your share using `valid users = root` or `force user = root`

I personally use `force user =` in my shares, as I've grown tired of changes in SMB security screwing my share access up, due in part to how poorly Windows clients access and authenticate.